# How can we prove that the dimension of a plane is 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

By the question, I mean that what is the theoretical proof of it? How can we prove that the vector space of displacements take place in a plane is a 2-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Any base is made of two elements.

Comment: That's going to depend. What is your definition of "the plane", and what is your definition of "dimension"?

Comment: By "plane" I mean that the displacements in a plane... I want the mathematical proof of the number of dimension of displacements in a plane (we know it is two, but what is the proof?)

Comment: @Hossei Sharif Your question still makes little sense to me. What 'displacement' are you talking about?

Comment: I know [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)) isn't always the best source, but it defines a plane as: "a flat, two-dimensional surface that extends infinitely far". So the 2-dimension part is by definition, and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: You can't use "a plane" in the definition of a plane. That's circular.

Comment: @Arthur The question is tagged as "linear-algebra" and "vector-spaces". In this context it's pretty obvious that the dimension of a vector space V is the number of elements that a basis of V has. But you are right, that is going to depend. What is your definition of "basis"? What is your definition of "vector space"? What is your definition of "element"? What is your definition of "set"? What is your definition of "definition"? Why there should exist a definition of "definition"? Why do we exist? Can we be serious and stop asking non-sense, please?

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam It is not nonsense. Of course, there is a philosophical hell waiting for anyone who digs too deeply in that direction. But the fact remains that there can be several common definitions of both "dimension" and "plane". Which ones are chosen will change the phrasing of a proof. And even if there aren't alternatives, still reading those definitions thoroughly is the first step to solving this problem. Asking the OP to provide their definitions of those two terms will lead to better answers, if they don't discover the answer themselves in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of "the plane" are points. Assuming that you are talking about a Cartesian plane, you can describe your points by two coordinates $(x,y)$. We can write any point by a linear combination of the points $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ (i.e., $(x,y) = x(1,0) + y(0,1)$). Hence, $\{ (1,0), (0,1) \}$ is a generator set of the plane.

Any set with less elements (in that case, an unitary set) can not generate the plane. For example, if $\{ (x,y) \}$ is a potential generator set for the plane, we can't write the point $(x+1,y)$ as a linear combination of $(x,y)$.

So a set with less than two elements is not a generator set of the plane and a set of more than two elements is not linear independent (any third point in the set $\{ (1,0), (0,1) \}$  can be written as a linear combination of that two points), and that suffices to prove that the dimension of a plane is $2$.

(Sorry for the bad english, I'm still learning the language)

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks.

Comment: In fact, this expression proved that we can not generate plane vectors by just one vector and also any third vector in a plane can be generated by two vectors that we choose first.